# Is it still possible to web scrape data from a HTML Table if the <td> tags are the same?

Tags: r

I'm very new to R and web scraping in general. I am trying to take specific pieces of data from a HTML table through R but the  tags all have the same name in the table meaning if I try to take the data using the  name it takes more data than I need.

[Here is the page](https://www.transfermarkt.com/andreas-christensen/leistungsdatendetails/spieler/196948)

The table I'm trying to take from is obviously the huge one showing the statistics.

For example there is the < td class="zientriert"> throughout the table so when I try and take the data from that row it takes the data from every "zientriert" row. Is there any way to take the data I need and not take the data from every row?

Answer (score 1):

HTML table cells are uniquely identifiable, despite them having the same class. If they would not be, the data could not be entered. Relating to your question that answer would be yes :)

Scraping that information is easiest by using path selectors for the cell(s) you need. If you want just one cell, open up your developer tools (F12) in your browser and select the cell. I am running Firefox and you can also right-click and "Inspect Element".

If you then right-click in the HTML on the element you want to scrape => Copy => `selector` you'll get a set of selectors to choose from. For example, for the top row PPM of the page you supplied (2,67) the XPath selector is
`/html/body/div[6]/div[10]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]`.

Of course, this selector is unique to that cell. If you want to scrape more dynamically, it is definitely worthwhile to learn more about selectors and regular expressions to define a range. CSS selectors might be easier in that case given that you could extract data from those elements that are styled the same.

If you want to learn more about web scraping, it is important to understand how webpages are built (primarily HTML and CSS).

Answer (score 0):

Still some work needed to clean the data this gives you most of the data in a df

```
> library(tidyverse)
> library(rvest)
> 
> page <- xml2::read_html("https://www.transfermarkt.com/andreas-christensen/leistungsdatendetails/spieler/196948")
> 
> tbl <- html_table(page, fill = T)[[2]]
> head(tbl, 10)
   Season Competition      Competition reihenfolge ASC, saison_id DESC, verein_id ASC Club       PPM             
1             Total :          Total :                                             NA       199 1,81 11         8
2   18/19                Europa League                                             NA    6 2,67    -  - - / - / -
3   18/19               Premier League                                             NA    1 0,00    -  - 1 / - / -
4   18/19                      EFL Cup                                             NA    2 3,00    -  - - / - / -
5   18/19             Community Shield                                             NA    -    -    -  - - / - / -
6   17/18               Premier League                                             NA   27 1,67    -  - - / - / -
7   17/18                       FA Cup                                             NA    3 3,00    -  - - / - / -
8   17/18             Champions League                                             NA    6 1,50    -  - - / - / -
9   17/18                      EFL Cup                                             NA    4 1,75    -  - - / - / -
10  17/18             Community Shield                                             NA    -    -    -  - - / - / -
       /   /        
1  3 / - / - 17.068'
2       540'    <NA>
3        90'    <NA>
4       139'    <NA>
5          -    <NA>
6     2.071'    <NA>
7       230'    <NA>
8       454'    <NA>
9       341'    <NA>
10         -    <NA>
```